# Storing the user name as part of the XAdES signature

Tags: xades4j, xml-dsig

Several users using a web app can electronically sign documents using the company key and certificate. The signature is produced in the XAdES format. I'd like to keep a trace, in the signature itself, of the user name who asked for signing. First, i'm not sure if it's a *licit* thing to do.

If so, does anyone know the XML element in which it makes sense to store that piece of information ? I just cannot find one that suits this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML-DSIG/XAdES define elements that contain X509-related data (e.g. `X509SubjectName`). Usually each user would have his certificate and if you included the aforementioned elements they'd have the information you need.

Since you have a single certificate I'd say any additional data is application-specific. You could use, for instance, a `ds:Object` element which is also signed. In xades4j you can do this using [`EnvelopedXmlObject`](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources#envelopedxmlobject).

Comment: Thanks, I kept searching in the XAdES specification and didn't think about the XML-DSIG spec. The ds:Object should do it.